# ActiveX controls in Excel 2013 64 bit

Tags: vba, excel, activex

I've developed a number of excel tools which include ActiveX controls from the developer tab and VBA. They all work in Excel 2013 **32 bit**. However one of my clients is using Excel 2013 **64 bit** and the tools do not function on his PC. I understand that this is probably due to the ActiveX controls. (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee681792.aspx)

is there a simple way to make my tools excel 2013 64 bit compatible? preferably without having to install office 2013 64 bit and having to re-work them all?

Comment: You *made* ActiveX controls? Or you made tools *using* ActiveX controls?

Comment: @Mat'sMug I made tools _using_ ActiveX controls. Using the Developer tab and Insert to add them to a worksheet. the're all simple ones like comboboxes and Listboxes, but with vba code behind them.

Comment: Per the MSDN article you linked, you're going to need to maintain and ship 32 and 64 bit versions.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you used ActiveX controls rather than normal form controls? Perhaps to use their events? If not then you can programatically replace them all with form controls.

Answer (score 0):

ActiveX has more controls, with other options.

Excel 2013 x64: Doesn't have "SerialPort" in form controls. is an activex control